# Swift ios not sure if I am using completion handler right

Tags: ios, swift

When I login into my app I am removing two VC's that are presented as modal and then adding a new VC and making it root VC by:

```
@IBAction func loginButtonDidTouch(sender: AnyObject) {
    let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let AccountVc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AccountVc")

    let navigationController = self.view.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController        

    self.presentingViewController!.presentingViewController!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false) { () -> Void in                
        navigationController.setViewControllers([AccountVc], animated: true)                
    }
}
```

What I want to make sure is that `navigationController.setViewControllers([AccountVc], animated: true)` runs once `self.presentingViewController!.presentingViewController!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false)` is done.

It works but I am not sure if this is the right way to write it?

I am writing: `{ () -> Void in` I see some examples where people only write it without Void.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both ways are right. This is called `Trailing Closures`.

```
func someFunctionThatTakesAClosure(closure: () -> Void) {
    // function body goes here
}

// here's how you call this function without using a trailing closure:

someFunctionThatTakesAClosure({
    // closure's body goes here
})

// here's how you call this function with a trailing closure instead:

someFunctionThatTakesAClosure() {
    // trailing closure's body goes here
}
```

See more at [Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94)